# APCUPSD: Cannot find UPS on ANY serial port

Tags: 16.04, server, serial-port, ups

I have APCUPSD installed on a computer with 2 physical serial ports. The UPS is an APC SUA1000 with a serial port. I have the APC smart serial cable connected to COM1, and COM2 going to another computer.

`ls -l /dev/ttyS*` reports ttyS0 all of the way up to ttyS31.

I have tried literally every one of those ports to no avail.

/etc/default/apcupsd:

https://pastebin.com/ePihcZK0

/var/log/apcupsd.events:

https://pastebin.com/z04EiDKF

/etc/apcupsd.conf:

https://pastebin.com/kiFwLimY

Running `apcaccess` also fails with a 'connection refused' error. Yes, I have edited my `/etc/hosts` file to correct the localhost... thing.

I'm stumped. Can anyone help please? Thanks.

OS: Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 i386.

Answer (score 0):

Note to self: don't expect an RS232 cable to work with an RS422 port.

Solved by using an RS232 port.

Comment: You can accept your answer in a day or so if you think it will help others. The other option is to delete both your answer and question.